# perl: how does `$1` behave in a loop?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm getting some behavior I don't understand in perl:

```
>>> my @words = ('hello', 'there');
>>> $words[0] =~ /(el)/; print $1;
el
>>> $words[1] =~ /(el)/; print $1;
undef
```

but in a loop:

```
>>> my @words = ('hello', 'there');
>>> foreach my $word (@words){
>>>    $word =~ /(el)/;
>>>    print "$1\n";
>>> }
el
el
```

What's going on here? And how can I, in the loop, get $1 to be undefined when it doesn't match in the most recent regex, so that something like this will work:

```
foreach my $word (@words) {
    $word =~ /(el)/;
    if ($1) {
        print "$word matched\n";
    } else {
        print "$word did not match\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about the loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @words = ('hello', 'there');
$words[0] =~ /(el)/; say $1 // "[undef]";
$words[1] =~ /(el)/; say $1 // "[undef]";

my @words = ('hello', 'there');
foreach my $word (@words){
    $word =~ /(el)/;
    say $1 // "[undef]";
}
```

Output:

```
el
el
el
el
```

`$1` and friends are only changed on a successful match, so you want

```
for my $word (@words) {
    if ( $word =~ /el/ ) {
        print "$word matched\n";
    } else {
        print "$word did not match\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: the logic I'm using is a bit more complex than just printing the match. That was a simplified case I used to try to understand what's going on.  Is there any way to do what I want? i.e. set `$1`, `$2` (or something else) each time I get a match, and set them to `undef` if I don't get a match, for each iteration?

Comment: `my ($capture) = $word =~ /(el)/` and `my $capture = $word =~ /(el)/ ? $1 : undef;` set `$capture` in the manner you describe wanting `$1` set.

Comment: perfect. Does that mean I could use something along the lines of `my @matches = $word =~ /(list) (of) (match) (patterns)/;` to get an array of matches?

Comment: @ewok, Yes, it does. I avoid using `$1` in favour of these.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to avoid the special numbered variables entirely, which don't get reset in between runs. Instead, use a local variable, and reset it at the beginning of each loop:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @words = qw(
    one
    two
    three
);

for my $w (@words){
    my $store;

    if (($store = $w) =~ /(t)/){
        print "$store\n";
    }
    else {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
two
three
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return of the match:

```
if ($word =~ /(el)/) {
  print "$word matched with [$1]\n";
} else {
  print "$word did not match\n";
}
```

I suspect your test environment is doing a bit more when you run them separately than your script does, including reseting `$1`, among other things.